# IE can't handle jquery something.checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following coffeescript code works to read a checkbox in several browsers, but not in IE:

```
if something.checked
```

HTML:

```
      <input type="checkbox" name="something" id="something" >
```

With IE, I get

```
something undefined
```

Comment: how is `something` defined? what version of IE?

Comment: Try `var something = document.getElementById('something')`

Comment: How does that code work in several browsers?

Comment: @tymeJV: Some browsers turn ids into global variables.

Comment: @RocketHazmat -- Learn something new every day! Thanks!

Comment: It's in coffeescript - I just tried `if $("#overtime").is(":checked")` and that seems to work.

Comment: ^ That's one of _many_ different ways you could do it.  If you knew to try that, why didn't you try it before asking this question? You could also do `$('#overtime').prop('checked')`

Comment: @jahroy And that's definitely the better way of checking its `checked` state

Answer (score 1):

Having an element named "something" does not magically bind it to JavaScript. You need to create an event handler first.

```
document.getElementById('something').onclick = function(element) {
    ...your code ...
})
```

Comment: Actually, it does. But it's probably not consistent across browsers. Specifically setting the `id` can create properties on `window`